# Rails redirect_to arbitrary url with subdomain support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, rails-routing

I'm using Rails 5.1 and here's the problem:

I need to redirect my current user to a url of his choosing just after signing in but at the same time I need to take him to an exact application subdomain.

For example,

1. The user types `myapp.com/users`
2. The user is redirected to the login screen `myapp.com/login`.
3. Upon successful sign in the user is expected to be taken at `foo.myapp.com/users`.

But instead the user is being redirected to just `myapp.com/users` without subdomain redirection.

I've managed to get as far as this line but subdomain forwarding seems to not be working:

```
subdomain = foo
redirect_to session[:forwarding_url], subdomain: subdomain
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The redirect_to should look something the code below.

Note we're using the rails ActionController::UrlFor  you may need to include it:

```
include UrlFor
```

The example is going to the controller 'home' with the action 'home' and the subdomain returned by subdomain_params.
You can set the controller, action, and subdomain_params how ever you'd like.  In your example

```
def subdomain_params
  "foo"
end

redirect_to url_for(controller: 'home', action: "home", subdomain: subdomain_params)
```